# How to move mouse with 2 fingers on trackpad?

Tags: macos, trackpad

How can I change the default behaviour for the two-fingers gesture from scrolling to mouse movement?

That is to say:

When I put two fingers on my trackpad, and move them, I want the mouse pointer on-screen to move. I do not want the window to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of apps that I know of that does this kind of thing:

- [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/)
- [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/)

Screenshots from BTT (left) and MP (right)

[image]
[image]

*Disclaimer:  These are not tools I use personally (no need) so I cannot vouch for them. However, BTT has a trial and MP is free.*  So, your risk is minimal if you want to test either of these out.

Comment: MagicPrefs doesn't work for what I want, and i can't find an option in BetterTouchTool

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: when I put two fingers on the trackpad and move them, I want the mouse pointer to move on screen. I do not want the page to scroll.

Comment: You can disable all scrolls if it really bothers you from Accessibility section in the System Preferences.

Comment: BetterTouchTool allows for much more granularity in defining trackpad gestures - e.g. you are able to define a 2-finger-on-track-gesture/behaviour specifically for the Finder. But you have to assign what should happen where e.g. for a specific program or globally, there is no checkbox to untick to simply get what you want.